# Share full resolution photos on Twitter, Instagram, etc

Tags: 8.0, lumia, camera, twitter, instagram

Is there any way I can share my full resolution photos on Twitter and other social networks? I recently bought the Nokia Lumia Icon, and it has a 20 MP camera. The original photos are very nice but they look like trash when you share them on social networks! I know they're converted to a 5MP picture when shared but is there a way to share them with full resolution?

Comment: Wouldn't that be up to each social network? Instagram, for instance, is low-res by design. If you want to share high-resolution photos, try OneDrive or maybe Flickr.

Comment: The Twitter app for windows phone actually saves a scaled down version of the file. Flickr/OneDrive are the only things that seem to accept full res.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only way to access the high-res images is via PC or a third-party file explorer app (e.g. [Files](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=762e837f-461d-4847-8399-3526f54fc25e).
The inbuilt sharing button doesn't give you access to those high-res images.